# Google APIs Client Library for PHP invalid key

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-api-php-client

I am trying to use the api to access storage bucket with the following code:

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("JJJJ-app-143412");
$client->setDeveloperKey("JJJJ-83a8528076ce.json");

$storage = new Google_Service_Storage($client);
```

In the code above "JJJJ-83a8528076ce.json" is the file which I had downloaded while creating service account and "JJJJ-app-143412" is the application name.

But when I try to execute this code, it throws the following error:

```
{ "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "usageLimits", "reason": "keyInvalid", "message": "Bad Request" } ], "code": 400, "message": "Bad Request" } }
```

I think that API key that is being set is incorrect. Could anyone let me know where to get the API key to be used in setDeveloperKey() method ?

Thanks

Comment: that's not an api key.   That's a json file.   There is a difference.

Comment: Yeah, but where exactly do you get the developerKey from to be used in setDeveloperKey() method?

Comment: Developer key is the public api key you create on google developer console for accessing Public data.